# How do I toggle to full screen resolution?

Tags: death-rally-2012

Game starts to me on windowed mode, I go to settings and click on `Windowed` button but it won't change to Full Screen.

How can I full screen it!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you switch the game resolution to 1280x960 (60-75 hz) you will be able to change to fullscreen.

Found here: http://community.remedygames.com/showthread.php?t=9093#post155332